# How to create a commenting page like Instagram in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am building a social network App and I need a commenting page like the on in Instagram or any other App, I have tried the following:

```
CGPoint buttonPosition = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:_postsTableView];
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [_postsTableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:buttonPosition];

UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
LikesViewController *controller = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LikesViewController"];
controller.postid = postid[indexPath.row];

[self presentViewController:controller animated:NO completion:nil];
```

but I need a `UITableView` with a footer that has a `UITextField`, the page should display the previous comments and have the option to let the user add new comments, can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance.

Comment: With the help of an `Array` + `TableView` + `Buttons` + `TextField` ?

Answer (score 0):

**@ViewDidLoad**

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapReceived:)];
    [tapGestureRecognizer setDelegate:self];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];
```

**Dismiss keyboard & end editing when tapped outside**

```
-(void)tapReceived:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tapGestureRecognizer
{
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
}
```

**Keyboard methods**

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardDidShow:) name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardDidHide:) name:UIKeyboardDidHideNotification object:nil];

    [self.view endEditing:YES];
    return YES;
}
- (void)keyboardDidShow:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    // Assign new frame to your view
    CGSize keyboardSize = [[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.1 animations:^{
        CGRect f = self.view.frame;
        f.origin.y = -keyboardSize.height + 180;
        self.view.frame = f;
    }];

}

-(void)keyboardDidHide:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.1 animations:^{
        CGRect f = self.view.frame;
        f.origin.y = 0.0f;
        self.view.frame = f;
    }];
}
```

Feel free to adjust the animation duration as you see fit.Good luck

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but all this functionality is already done and saved on a database, my problem is with the UI, because i am new to iOS, i need that uitextfield that goes up with the keyboard when you click inside, stuff like that...

Comment: modified my answer, let me know if it addresses your concern